# Proving two countably infinite sets have a one-to-one correspondence.

Tags: analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets. Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are both countably infinite sets. Prove that there is a one-to-one correspondence between $A$ & $B$.

Here is the proof I have. I tried going about the proof by first show $f: A \rightarrow N$ has a one-to-one correspondence and $g: B \rightarrow N$ as a one-to-one correspondence as well. Not sure if this was the right thing to do. Then I did theta: $A \rightarrow B$. Not sure if I defined theta right and accurately showed that there is a one-to-one correspondence between $A$ and $B$.

Proof: Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are both countably infinite sets. As a result of the two sets being countably infinite, we know set $A$ and $B$ can be put in a one-to-one correspondence with the set of positive integers. Thus we need to find a one-to-one correspondence between $N$ to $A$ and $N$ to $B$.

Lets define $$f: A \rightarrow N \,|\, f(n)= 2n, \,\, \forall n\in \{A\}$$

Then suppose there is a a,b in the set $A$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$ $\rightarrow$ $2a = 2b$ $\rightarrow a=b$.
Therefore, there is a one-to-one correspondence.

Similarly, define
$$g: B \rightarrow N \,|\, f(m) = 2m-1, \,\, \forall m \in \{B\}$$

Then suppose there is a $c,d$ in the $B$ such that $g(c)=g(d)$ $\rightarrow 2c-1 =2d-1$ $\rightarrow 2c=2d$ $\rightarrow c=d$

Therefore, there is a one-to-one correspondence.

The $|A|=|B|=|N|$ $(N \in \{\mathbb{N}\})$

Now, let $\theta: A \rightarrow B$ via $\theta(2n)=2n-1$ for all $n$ in the set $N$

Suppose $x,y$ in the set $N$ such that $\theta(x)=\theta(y)$.
$\theta(x) = \theta(y)$ $\rightarrow 2x-1 =2y-1 \rightarrow 2x=2y \rightarrow x=y$

Hence there is a one-to-one correspondence between the two countably infinite sets $A$ & $B$.

Comment: Are A and B specific sets, or place holders for "any two countably infinite sets". Because if it's the latter, you really need to stay away from explicitly defining the bijections (the other name for "1-1 correspondence"). Hint: "countably infinite" is *defined* as "in a bijection with N".

Comment: A and B are place holders for "any two countably infinite sets"

Comment: @Yogibear (1) How do you define countably infinite? (2) If there are bijections $R\to T$ and $S\to T$, can you see how to get a bijection $R\to S$?

Comment: @almagest - In the book it says a set is countably infinite if it has the same cardinality as N. Does this mean that I can skip the steps of showing that f: A-->N is a 1-to-1 since it follows that since it is a countably infinite set which means |A|=|N|? Then could I then infer since both A --> N and B--> N, then A-->B since they both have the same cardinality as N?

Comment: @Yogibear More or less. $A$ is countably infinite means there is a bijection $a:A\to\mathbb{N}$. Similarly, $B$ countably infinite means there is a bijection $b:B\to\mathbb{N}$. Note that $b^{-1}:\mathbb{N}\to B$ is *also* a bijection, and hence so is $a$ followed by $b^{-1}$.

Comment: "Lets define
f:A→N|f(n)=2n,∀n∈{A}"  But what if $A$ is not a set of numbers? "Then suppose there is a a,b in the set A such that f(a)=f(b) → 2a=2b →a=b. Therefore, there is a one-to-one correspondence."  But it's not surjective!  No odd numbers are being mapped to.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is asking for an abstract proof. The first step is to state your givens and your goal:

The set $A$ is countably infinite. The set $B$ is countably infinite.

We want to prove the at $A$ and $B$ are the same size.

Doing this may seem trivial, but it helps to clarify what you have and what you want.

Then we figure out what definitions are relevant. In this case, there are two:

A set $S$ is "countably infinite" if there is a bijection from $S$ to $\mathbb{N}$, the set of natural numbers.

Two sets $S$ and $T$ are "the same size" if there exists a bijection from $S$ to $T$.

The definition of bijection is only important insofar as the next step, looking over what we have already proven, and can thus use in this proof.

Have you (or your book) proven that bijections are invertible? That the inverse of a bijection is also a bijection? That the composition of two bijections is itself a bijection? If not, try to prove them now. All of these facts are vital to this proof.

With all that out of the way, we can begin with the actual proof:

We know $A$ is countably infinite, which in turn means there is a bijection from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$. Call this bijection $a$.

Note that we do *not* define $a(x)$. This is because we have *no idea* what $x$ looks like other than "an element of $A$". $x$ could be an integer, a real number, a complex number, a color, a person, the empty set, whatever! All we know, and need to know, is that a bijection from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$ exists, and we are calling it $a$.

Moving on: We also know that that $B$ is countably infinite, so there is a bijection from $B$ to $\mathbb{N}$. Call it $b$; again, we do *not* define $b(y)$, for the same reasons as above. We know a bijection from $B$ to $\mathbb{N}$ exists, and we are calling it $b$.

Now we need to show that there is a bijection from $A$ to $B$. Unfortunately, we only have bijections from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$ (the function $a$) and from $B$ to $\mathbb{N}$ (the function $b$). What to do?

First, we invert $b$, giving us $b^{-1}$. How? Since $b$ is a bijection, $b^{-1}$ exists and is a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $B$. In fact, it is a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $B$.

Second, we compose $a$ and $b^{-1}$ to produce $b^{-1} a$. How? Since $a$ is a bijection from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$ and $b^{-1}$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $B$, they can be composed (in the order given) to form a function from $A$ to $B$. In fact, it is a bijection from $A$ to $B$.

And thus, we have a bijection from $A$ to $B$, and thus, $A$ and $B$ are the same size. QED.

As a follow up, can you prove that $B$ and $A$ are the same size?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming countably infinite means there is a bijection between the $\mathbb N$ and the set.

So if $A$ and $B$ are both countably infinite then we know there must exist two bijections

$\phi: \mathbb N \to A$, and $\psi: \mathbb N\to B$.

Then I claim that $f = \psi\circ \phi^{-1}$ is a well defined bijection.

Can you prove that?

Just use the definitions.  First prove $\phi^{-1}:B\to \mathbb N$ defined by: for any $a\in A$ then $\phi^{-1}(a)$ will be equal to the unique $n\in \mathbb N$ so that $\phi(n)= a$; is well defined.

Then prove $\phi^{-1}$ is a bijection.

Then prove the composition of bijections is a bijection.

Then prove $\psi\circ \phi^{-1}$  is surjective and one-to-one.

......

Step 1:  $\phi^{-1}: \mathbb A\to \mathbb N$ is well defined.

$\phi:\mathbb N\to A$ is surjective. SO for ever $a\in A$ there is an $n\in \mathbb N$ so that $\phi(n) = a$.  And as $\phi$ is one-to-one, there is only one distinct $n$ so that $\phi(n) = a$.  So for every $a$ we can unique identify a distinct and unique $n_a$ so that $\phi(n_a) = a$ and we can define a function so that $\phi^{-1}(n_a) =a$ for each $a \in A$.  SO $\phi^{-1}:A\to \mathbb N$ is well defined.

Step 2: $\phi^{-1}: A\to \mathbb N$ is a bijection.

a) $\phi^{-1}$ is surjective. Pf:  $\phi:\mathbb N \to A$ so for any $n\in \mathbb N$ there is an $a\in A$ so that $\phi(n) = a$.  So by definition $\phi^{-1}(a) = n$.  SO for every $n$ there is an $a\in A$ so that $\phi^{-1}(a) = n$.  SO $\phi^{-1}$ is surjective.

b) $\phi^{-1}$ is one to one.  Pf: Suppose $\phi^{-1}(a) =\phi^{-1}(\alpha)$.  Label that $n =\phi^{-1}(a) =\phi^{-1}(\alpha))$.  Then by definition $\phi(n) =a$ and $\phi(n) =\alpha)$.  But $\phi$ is a *function*.  It maps every value of $n$ to *one* (and only one) value of $A$.  So we must have $a =\alpha$.  So $\phi^{-1}$ is one to one.

So $\phi^{-1}$ is a bijection.

(Note: this argument and proof would work for *any* bijection between any two sets.  All bijections will have an inverse function and the inverse will be a bijection.

Step 3:  Prove $\psi\circ \phi^{-1}:\mathbb A \to B$ is a bijection.

a) $\psi\circ \phi^{-1}$ is surjective: Pf: Suppose $b\in A$.  Then as $\psi$ is surjective there is an $n_b\in \mathbb N$ so that $\psi(n_b) = b$.

And $\phi^{-1}$ is surjective so there is an $a \in A$ so the $\phi^{-1}(a) = n_b$.

So $\psi(\phi^{-1}(a)) = \psi(n_b) = b$. So there is an $a\in A$ so that $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}(a) = b$.  So $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}$ is surjective.

b) $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}$ is one to one.  Suppose $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}(a)=\psi\circ\phi^{-1}(\alpha) = b$.

Let $\phi^{-1}(\alpha) = n$ and $\phi^{-1}(a)= m$.  Then $\psi(n)=\psi(\phi^{-1}(\alpha)) = b$ and $\psi(m)=\psi(\phi^{-1}(a)) = b$.  But $\psi$ is one to one so $n=m$ and $\phi^{-1}(\alpha) = \phi^{-1}(a)$.

But $\phi^{-1}$ is one to one so $\alpha = a$.  so if $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}(a)=\psi\circ\phi^{-1}(\alpha)\implies a=\alpha$ so $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}$ is one to one.

SO $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}$ is a bijection between $A$ and $B$.

Not... all this would hold for any two sets of the same (any) cardinality.

If $|M| = |N|$ and $|N| = |C|$ there always exists a bijection between $M$ and $C$ and $|M| = |C|$>

Answer (score 0):

There is already a good answer. This can be looked upon differently.

Since $A$ and $B$ are countable, let us list their elements, i.e. $A=\{a_1, a_2, \cdots\}$ and $B=\{b_1, b_2, \cdots\}$ (all distinct elements). Define the one-to-one correspondences $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ by $f(a_i)=i$ and $g:B \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ by $g(b_i)=i$. Then $g^{-1} \circ f$ is the required one-to-one correspondence from $A$ to $B$.

But if you list the elements as, $A=\{\cdots, a_{-2}, a_{-1}, a_0, a_1, a_2, \cdots\}$, similar formula for $B$. The one-to-one correspondence would be $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ define by $f(a_i)=2i$, if $i\geq 0$; $f(a_i)= -(2i+1)$ if $i<0$. Similarly define $g:B \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. $g^{-1}\circ f$ is the one-to-one correspondence as before.